# Issue with passing an image struct to tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

This is the struct that I have...

```
struct ProductImage {
   let id : String
   let url : URL
   let isDefault : Bool
}

struct Product {
    let name : String
    let id : String
    var images = [ProductImage]()

    init(name : String, id: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }

    mutating func add(image: ProductImage) {
        images.append(image)
    }
}
```

Now I have an image loaded on the collectionview and on the click of a button, I want to pass this image to a tableviewcell. But how that can be achieved that I'm not able to figure out. The collectionview does have a couple of labels with name and id which is passed like so...

```
func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

   let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell))

   self.photoThumbnail = self.arrayOfURLImages[(indexPath?.row)!]

   let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productSellIdentifier") as! sellTableViewController

   let productObject = productData1[(indexPath?.row)!]

        if selectedItems == nil { //selectedItems is an array which will hold all struct items.
          selectedItems = [Product(name:productObject.name, id: productObject.id)]

        } else {
            selectedItems?.append(productObject)

         }
      myVC.arrProduct = selectedItems
        navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true) }
```

Hope somebody can help...Thanks...

Comment: does each `collectionViewCell` from your `collectionView` contain that  `sell Button` ?

Comment: Yes..you are right @Lamar. It does contain a sell button...

Comment: The code snippet starting with `func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {...` is for that itself...

Comment: But the data related to name and id is being shown properly. I'm not able send the image properly from the structs as it has been done for the name and id. That's where the issue is I feel...What do you think..?

Comment: oh you didn't say that into the description, so you are saying that things are properly passed into your tableView except the images, are those images coming from an api ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157234/discussion-between-lamar-and-bws).